# Comparing AR Models in R when AIC isn't available

Tags: autoregressive

I need to compare between an AR(4) and AR(5) model, but when I try to estimate the AR(4) model, I received the following result:

Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [1]

AR1 through 3 and 5 and 6 were estimated without issue (and I've narrowed it down to AR(5) and AR(4) at this point), but this was the only one that gave me a problem.

I can estimate the model by CSS, but this would only give me the partial log-likelihood. I've read elsewhere that this isn't a good estimate for log-likelihood, so I wouldn't be able to compute the AIC/BIC/AICc by hand and compare between this and the other models.

Is there another way I can compare between the two models? Another possibility I considered was estimating both, AR(5) with ML and AR(4) with CSS, and then computing in-sample RMSE's.

Comment: Why not try to find out why there's error for AR(4) models? If it has to do something with the data, then it'll affect your other models too.

Comment: Maybe try different starting values and the optimization algorithm will converge? Or a different optimization algorithm, if available?

Comment: I'm not sure why there's an error message, unfortunately. The error I received is above, and I've tried to research it, but I haven't quite been able to find anything.

Comment: Also, I tried that as well: CSS-ML estimation won't work for some reason. I can only estimate the model if I use CSS. Surprisingly, however, I can estimate the model with ML in Stata, from which I can obviously back out AIC.